How to make a grid of a map preserving grids at country frontiers?
I want to make a grid map (hexagonal) while preserving the grids at the frontiers.
As you can see from the code I share bellow the grids are cropped in the country (Portugal) frontier, but I would like to have the grids at the frontier preserved.
Could you help me on this?
Thanks
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)


nuts1_continente <- giscoR::gisco_get_nuts(
  nuts_id = "PT1",
  year = "2021", # depends on the data, if old or recent
  resolution = "1", # 3
  nuts_level = "1",
  update_cache = TRUE
)


continente_utm <-
  st_transform(nuts1_continente, 25829)

################### Create Grid - HEX Intersected ####

hex_grid_map <- continente_utm |>
  sf::st_make_grid(
    square = FALSE, cellsize = 22800, crs = st_crs(continente_utm)
  ) |>
  st_intersection(continente_utm) |>
  st_sf() |>
  mutate(grid_id = seq_len(n()))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = continente_utm) +
  geom_sf(data = hex_grid_map, alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_void()


The hex grids are space filling (depending on size of hex), have you tried the above without the st_intersection(continente_utm) |> ?

Yes, I did, however it is not what I was expecting, since the grids exist throughout the bounding box of the map.

So the idea is to have grid only until boundary? see sf::st_contains_properly, explore sf::st_contains, or perhaps buffer (outward) Portugal border then create grid under st_contains_properly constraint. Will look at tomorrow.

This is my workflow for generating hex grids. This process ensures that hexagons remain unclipped based on your specified boundaries
# 1. Code for downloading data is the same as yours.

# 2. I create an object and update the CRS according to the projection.

portugal_update_crs <- st_transform(continente_utm, crs = 25829)

# 3. Build a second object for the hex grid. 

hex_grid <- continente_utm %>% 
  st_make_grid(square = FALSE,
               cellsize = 22800,  
               crs = st_crs(continente_utm)) 

# 4. Select the hexagons that are included in the first object. This process does not crop the hexagons.

portugal_hex <- hex_grid[portugal_update_crs]

# final plot

portugal_hex %>%
ggplot()+
geom_sf()+
theme_void()



This is good and if you plot (add) as well Portugal border,would likely be accepted answer should the border be within the outermost hex.

Omg yes! thank you! It was a typo. Already fix
